# Why does reading localStorage values require a page refresh to show CSS changes toggled by jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css, local-storage, darkmode

I'm trying to use the value of `localStorage` to display one of two Twitter feeds, one for a light mode theme, the other for dark mode. It works, but I have to refresh the webpage for the correct CSS - either `twitter-dark-display-none` or `twitter-light-display-none` - to work.

Using `jQuery(document).ready(function ()` doesn't help.

The Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zpsf5q3x/2/ But the sample tweets don't show due to JSFiddle limits on displaying third party frames. And, localstorage may not work there, either.

Fiddle calls two external libraries:
`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css` and `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js`

HTML:

*Note the `data-theme="dark"` in the first block.*

```
<div class="twitter-dark-display-none">
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="170" data-height="200" data-theme="dark"
 data-tweet-limit="1" data-chrome="transparent nofooter noborders" href="https://twitter.com/StackOverflow?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets</a>
</div>

<div class="twitter-light-display-none">
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="170" data-height="200" data-tweet-limit="1" data-chrome="transparent nofooter noborders" href="https://twitter.com/StackOverflow?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets</a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

Overall function that uses localStorage to toggle the entire site between dark and normal mode.

```
$('body').toggleClass(localStorage.toggled);
function darkLight() {
  if (localStorage.toggled != 'dark') {
    $('body').toggleClass('dark', true);
    localStorage.toggled = "dark";
  } else {
    $('body').toggleClass('dark', false);
    localStorage.toggled = "";
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to use to toggle CSS:

```
  if (localStorage.toggled === 'dark') {
    
        $('.twitter-light-display-none').addClass("display-none");
        $('.twitter-dark-display-none').addClass("display-block");
    
      } else {
    
        $('.twitter-dark-display-none').addClass("display-none");
        $('.twitter-light-display-none').addClass("display-block");
    
    }
```

CSS:

```
.display-none {
    display: none !important;
}

.display-block {
    display: block !important;
}
```

---

**Edit 10/24/2020:**

`johannchopin's` answer works, with the addition of `$('body').toggleClass(localStorage.toggled);`
as in my original code above.

**But**. There is some sort of conflict with the `gitbrent` dark mode JS and CSS libraries, so I switched to `https://github.com/coliff/dark-mode-switch` and that  results in a simpler way to both toggle dark mode and use localstorage in addition to the function `johannchopin` provided to switch between twitter widget divs:

```
<script>

(function() {
  var darkSwitch = document.getElementById("darkSwitch");
  if (darkSwitch) {
    initTheme();
    darkSwitch.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
      resetTheme();
    });
    function initTheme() {
      var darkThemeSelected =
        localStorage.getItem("darkSwitch") !== null &&
        localStorage.getItem("darkSwitch") === "dark";
      darkSwitch.checked = darkThemeSelected;
      darkThemeSelected
        ? document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark")
        : document.body.removeAttribute("data-theme");
    }
    function resetTheme() {
      if (darkSwitch.checked) {
        document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
        localStorage.setItem("darkSwitch", "dark"); 
} else {
        document.body.removeAttribute("data-theme");
        localStorage.removeItem("darkSwitch");  
      }
  updatedarkSwitch();
    }
  }
})();

function updatedarkSwitch() {
  if (localStorage.darkSwitch === 'dark') {
    $('.twitter-light-display-none').addClass("display-none").removeClass('display-block');
    $('.twitter-dark-display-none').addClass("display-block").removeClass('display-none');
  } else {
    $('.twitter-dark-display-none').addClass("display-none").removeClass('display-block');
    $('.twitter-light-display-none').addClass("display-block").removeClass('display-none');
  }
}
updatedarkSwitch()
</script>
```

And then use the most basic dark mode rule in the style sheet:

```
[data-theme="dark"] {
background-color: #000000 !important;
}

and also add any other more specific CSS rules needed, i.e.

[data-theme="dark"] .post-title{
color:#fff !important;
}
```

Comment: Please add all of the code necessary to reproduce the issue in your jsfiddle. We need to see the behavior + the code in order to help

Comment: All the code is there; the tweets don't show due to JSFiddle limits on displaying third party frames. And, localstorage may not work there, either.

Comment: Check your jsfiddle again. Your JavaScript is not wired up to the buttons. All you have there is an if/else statement. Where are your event listeners?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have multiple issues in you code. First, you toggle the CSS, but only when the page loads because this code is only run once (when the script is loaded):

```js
if (localStorage.toggled === 'dark') {
  // ...
```

Just move this script in the function (ex: `updateInterfaceTheme`) that you call at the end of `darkLight()`.

Another issue is that you forget to clean the previous class and that leads to a styling conflict:

```js
$('.twitter-light-display-none').addClass("display-none"); // class .display-block still exist
$('.twitter-dark-display-none').addClass("display-block"); // class .display-none still exist
```

So don't forget to clean them:

```js
 if (localStorage.toggled === 'dark') {
    $('.twitter-light-display-none').addClass("display-none").removeClass('display-block');
    $('.twitter-dark-display-none').addClass("display-block").removeClass('display-none');
  } else {
    $('.twitter-dark-display-none').addClass("display-none").removeClass('display-block');
    $('.twitter-light-display-none').addClass("display-block").removeClass('display-none');
  }
```

And like that it's working:

```js
function darkLight() {
  if (localStorage.toggled !== 'dark') {
    $('body').toggleClass('dark', true);
    localStorage.toggled = "dark";
  } else {
    $('body').toggleClass('dark', false);
    localStorage.toggled = "";
  }

  updateInterfaceTheme();
}

function updateInterfaceTheme() {
  if (localStorage.toggled === 'dark') {
    $('.twitter-light-display-none').addClass("display-none").removeClass('display-block');
    $('.twitter-dark-display-none').addClass("display-block").removeClass('display-none');
  } else {
    $('.twitter-dark-display-none').addClass("display-none").removeClass('display-block');
    $('.twitter-light-display-none').addClass("display-block").removeClass('display-none');
  }
}

updateInterfaceTheme()
```

```css
.display-none {
  display: none !important;
}

.display-block {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="switch"><span class="switchtext">Dark</span>
  <input type="checkbox" data-style="ios" data-onstyle="outline-secondary" data-offstyle="outline-secondary" data-size="sm" data-toggle="toggle" onchange="darkLight()">
  <span class="slider"></span><span class="switchtext">Mode</span>
</label>

<div class="twitter-dark-display-none">Dark Mode
  <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="170" data-height="200" data-theme="dark" data-tweet-limit="1" data-chrome="transparent nofooter noborders" href="https://twitter.com/StackOverflow?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets</a>
</div>

<div class="twitter-light-display-none">Light Mode
  <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="170" data-height="200" data-tweet-limit="1" data-chrome="transparent nofooter noborders" href="https://twitter.com/StackOverflow?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets</a>
</div>
```

### Checkout the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0bmLnfh5/19/) to see it working with localStorage.

Comment: Thanks! That's a good try, but dark/light mode doesn't persist across page reloads or navigation to other pages; dark/light mode gets toggled off with a page reload.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Yes it. Switch to dark mode and refresh the page, you will see that only the `Dark Mode Tweets` text is shown. Switch again to light and refresh, you will just see the `Light Mode Tweets` text. If you speak about the checkbox you didn't write any code about this one. Should I add this feature to the answer?

Comment: The original code in my question *correctly allows dark/light mode to persist across page loads*; that was never the problem. The problem has always been forcing the CSS on the twitter divs to display correctly *without needing to refresh* the page.

Comment: What do you mean with `dark/light mode gets toggled off with a page reload`? Check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0bmLnfh5/19/) and you will see that on page reload the correct section is shown according to the theme (so it is persistant) :/ What feature exactly is missing in my code? the checkbox that still check on dark mode?

Comment: Ah, one problem is that I have in my Fiddle two included libraries: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css and https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js . But, I have those, of course, in my localhost, and still the dark/light mode does not persist across page loads.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Please explain what `still the dark/light mode does not persist across page loads` mean??? What do you mean by that??? In my jsfiddle it is working like expected so you probably have another issue in you code that you don't mention in the question

Comment: Ah, hah; the problem is we're missing `$('body').toggleClass(localStorage.toggled);` that is in my original question and not in your Fiddle; that preserves the dark/light state on the body class across page reloads. Now it works on my localhost :)  We do need your function `updateInterfaceTheme` and the `removeClass` calls, too.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Ah you right I forget to add it because it doesn't add any value for the example. Is it fine now? ;)

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Perfect +1 Please don't forget to activate the bounty :)

Answer (score -1):

You should use method getItem().

```
let x = localStorage.getItem('toggled');
```

And than make a check for a variable.

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem

Comment: The [Web Storage API allows for getting and setting of storage items using the dot or bracket syntax (see Basic Concepts)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)